# Undefind Method 'root' error when i start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello im creating a login for my website using sourcery gem and this tutorial https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Simple-Password-Authentication

I have finished the tutorial.

When i try to start server i get this error.

Josephs-Mac-Pro:safsy josephk$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/joseph/Desktop/safsy/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`root' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

How do i fix this error? I followed the tutorial exactly.

Here is my routes file

```
root'users#index'
resources :user_sessions
resources :users

get 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
post 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  if @user.save
  redirect_to(:users, notice: 'User was successfully created')

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: Is this complete content of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Did you really put not `end`ed if block in controller?

Answer (score 4):

You have to wrap `routes.rb` content in block passed into `draw` method:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root'users#index'
  resources :user_sessions
  resources :users

  get 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
  post 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
end
```